# How to scroll back in Linux virtual consoles (2022)?

Tags: linux-kernel, tty, console

**I'm only talking about the generic Linux virtual console, not terminal emulators such as GNOME Terminal or remote login interfaces like PuTTY.**

It seems that some methods have been deprecated in newer Linux versions such as 5.19.
I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>, but it didn't work in Linux 5.19.2.
I prefer the virtual console because it needs fewer resources.

Comment: AFAIK in recent kernel releases Linux console became disaccelerated, so while "it needs fewer resources" it might be a whole lot slower than any graphical terminal emulator. And using screen/tmux to scroll back is a major PITA.

Comment: That question should not IMHO be closed duplicate since OP is asking for **how** when the answer on the other question just tells **why** and OP appears to already have the knowledge of the deprecation.

Comment: @MC68020 the answers to the linked questions also explain how. “This question already has answers here”, not “This question is the same as”.

Answer (score 3):

Scroll back [was](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=973c096f6a85e5b5f2a295126ba6928d9a6afd45) [removed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489) in version 5.9 of the kernel.

You can use a tool such as `screen` or `tmux` which provide their own scroll back buffer. For example in `screen`, press the `screen` hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> by default), then <kbd>Esc</kbd>; you can then scroll around the history using <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd> etc. <kbd>Esc</kbd> will leave this mode. The default scrollback is 100 lines, you can change this by setting `defscrollback` in `~/.screenrc` or specifying a scoll back size using the `-h` command-line option.

Comment: Why did they remove it?

Comment: @gomennathan the explanation is given in the commit messages — follow the two links in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Still running 5.4, I won't be able to test but because I do share your preference for tty (for system administration) AND since only one file (drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbcon.c) seems concerned by the [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/patch/?id=50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489) then :

I would rush trying to revert it :

1. Of course start backing up your kernel source tree,
2. Take a copy of the patch from the link given here-above:

   ```
   curl -L https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/patch/\?id\=50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489 > scrollback-fbcon.patch
   ```
3. Then actually reverse the patch; first do a dry run:

   ```
   patch -p1 -R --dry-run < scrollback-fbcon.patch
   ```

   and if everything looks OK (`man patch` if explanations needed for the report of the dry run), apply the patch:

   ```
   patch -p1 -R < scrollback-fbcon.patch
   ```
4. If everything looks OK then do proceed, rebuild your kernel and please do report here the result of your experience.

Comment: Why not use `git revert`?

Comment: @StephenKitt : because I should have assumed that OP's get the knowledge of **git** and also because, at the end of the day, it is not significantly easier ;-P

Comment: Having tried both, it seems to me that `git revert 50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489` and dealing with the fallout is easier than dealing with the `.rej` file, but that’s subjective of course. You’re still assuming enough knowledge on the reader’s part, with `patch` rather than with `git` (the reader needs to know to add `-p1`, and how to understand `.rej` files and fix the result).

Comment: @StephenKitt : I won't argue with you here&now on that IMHO peripheral question. My point going no further than : **DO REVERT THAT PATCH !** because in my experience of linux kernels up to 5.4, (not to say running a 5.4.195 with a dozen+ patches reverted) the probability of getting whatever hard-to-deal-with rejection when the patch concerns a unique file is minimum.